# LXDE & udev on Raspbian --Run script on USB Drive when plugged

Tags: linux, raspbian, udev, automount

Running LXDE on Raspbian.

I want to run a script on a usb flash drive when the device is plugged.  Any flash drive, not a specific one.

This is to provide code updates to customers without requiring a keyboard or mouse attached to one of several rpis in a system (they have displays but no input devices).  The customer will download a file to a thumbdrive on his own device and then insert it in one of four rpis in the system.  The script will "do what it needs" to backup old files and scp new ones to the correct hosts and remote directories in the system

I can write a udev rule that creates a symlink to the flash drive when plugged.  The symlink shows up  under /dev But, I can't cd into that symlink--I probably have to do a mount first.

By observation, LXDE seems to automount a USB flash drive in /media when plugged.  I don't see the name of the mount point (e.g. /media/B85D-6433) when using:

udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sda1) | grep -i 6433

or

udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sda1) | grep -i B85D

So, I can't figure out where the LXDE will mount the drive without first knowing its name.

1) Is there a way to determine the name of the directory under /media that LXDE will use for the mount point?  I could keep a list of what was in /media before and after the plug event and determine it that way, but maybe there's a better way?

2) Instead, should I mount the symlink under /dev to a different place then excecute the script on the usb drive via this new mount point?

3)  Other way?

Thanks!